# Jenkins:Jython script to access Jenkins remote API

Tags: api, jenkins

I'm building job using `jenkins-cli.jar`.
After building a job, I want to see the output details on the command prompt itself.

I.e. I need to fetch the jenkins console output details and show it in the command prompt.

Is it possible to do this task using a Jython script or is there any other simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by fetching the console text at $JENKINS_ROOT/job/<jobname>/<buildnumber>/consoleText